# CSS Syntax (very basic)

Tags: css

I would like to do the following thing and I am wondering about the best way to go about.

I have a div which is each 20% of the container's width (5 blocks). I would like to give a different background color to each block but only using one CSS class. What is the best way to do it?

In the past, I used to create 5 different classes where only the bg color is different (as everything else is the same - 20% width and same height) but I think there is a better way to do it.

Is it possible to create a class in the CSS that handles the different bg colors for each container?

Comment: No. You'd have to target each element individually to assign the background colour.

Comment: It completely depends on the way you structure your html. Can you give us an example? you can probably play around with the nth-child and adjacent sibling selectors

Comment: You can have multiple classes on your elements: `<div class="container bgblue">` wil have both container and bgblue classes -- in case you're worried about duplicating your width etc. settings.

Comment: do you mean something like this http://jsfiddle.net/doiks14/u3P96/?

Comment: Hi Andy, yes - exactly what I was going to achieve. thank you! It cleared up many things for me for the future. Thak you very much! And everybody else, thank you as well for the speedy response. :)

Comment: I'll put it up as a response then :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not very sure if it will work, but but can try this - have a same class for all the divs (as you are already having - say, the class is 'myDiv'). Then In css -

```
.myDiv:nth-child(1){
  background-color: red;
}
.myDiv:nth-child(2){
  background-color: blue;
}
.myDiv:nth-child(3){
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and so on..

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Play around with :nth-child or adjacent sibling selectors

Like so

```
.parent { width: 100%; }
.parent > div { width: 20%; float: left; }
.parent > div:nth-child(1) { background-color: black; }
.parent > div:nth-child(2) { background-color: blue; }
.parent > div:nth-child(3) { background-color: purple; }
.parent > div:nth-child(4) { background-color: orange; }
.parent > div:nth-child(5) { background-color: yellow; }
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/andyw_/u3P96/)

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/
in this link see css3 selector for li,div and ...

```
tr:nth-child(2n+1) /* represents every odd row of an HTML table */
tr:nth-child(odd)  /* same */
tr:nth-child(2n+0) /* represents every even row of an HTML table */
tr:nth-child(even) /* same */

/* Alternate paragraph colours in CSS */
p:nth-child(4n+1) { color: navy; }
p:nth-child(4n+2) { color: green; }
p:nth-child(4n+3) { color: maroon; }
p:nth-child(4n+4) { color: purple; }

/* Alternate division enter code herecolours in CSS */
.mydiv:nth-child(1) { color: navy; }
.mydiv:nth-child(2) { color: green; }
.mydiv:nth-child(3) { color: maroon; }
.mydiv:nth-child(4) { color: purple; }
```